# react-redux passing props to child component props

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, reactjs

I am trying to pass props to child component but the child is always receiving an empty.
Here's the code to make it clearer.

When I pass to child component a state, it works
**Here's the working code:**

```
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <PostList list={ this.state.posts }></PostList> 
  </div>
  );
}
```

But in my case, I want pass the props from the redux state

**Not working code:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <PostList list={ this.props.posts }></PostList>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    posts: state.posts.all,
    postDetail: state.posts.post
  }
}
```

Any ideas why the PostList is getting an empty object in the second case even though this.props.posts is not actually empty in the calling component?

Thanks

Comment: Please show whole component class and how you connect component to Redux store.

Comment: Are you using `connect()` ?

Comment: yes I have used connect() and this.props.posts appear right within the same component like if i did this.props.posts.map(x=> x) , it comes out right.. It's only when I try to put this.props.posts as a prop in <PostList list={this.props.posts} that it comes out empty in PostList

Comment: Can you add the code for PostList component at least where you use that prop

Comment: @JaredDykstra yes, this is intentional, i just created a local state for that component this.state = {posts : [items here]} it's being passed well when using that local state, but not when i use the one coming from mapStateToProps even though this.props.state works well within that component, not when i pass it as a prop to <PostList /> though

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @Sag1v no, no errors at all. just an empty array.

Comment: can you upload an example to github or include some more code like how you pass the store to the `provider` and `createStore`?

Comment: Please confirm what it is you are exporting.  I assume your `render()` method is contained within a class?  If so, ensure you export the result of `connect()`.  Something like this: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyReactClass)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand your question, showing the complete React component as well as the `connect()` call and `export`

Comment: Have you by accident mutated the redux state?

Comment: Post up all the relevant code including the parent component and the connect if you can. You may have another prop from another HoC, or it's own props overriding the 'posts' prop.

Answer (score 6):

Install [redux-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) to see what your redux state actually looks like.  For example, if you have used `combineReducers()`, then `.posts` may be prefixed with the name of a reducer.

Once you have verified the actual redux state, then double-check `mapStateToProps` to ensure you're referencing the correct state slice.  In your question, I wonder if you may need to adjust it, but I cannot be sure without first knowing what your redux state is.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  }
}
```

Please confirm what you are exporting. I assume your `render()` method is contained within a class? If so, ensure you export the result of `connect()`. Something like this:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyReactClass)
```

Comment: using redux-devtools, data is coming well within the same component, it's just when trying to pass it into <PostList /> as in <PostList list={this.props.posts} /> it goes in there empty. even thought this.props.posts is not empty within the component calling PostList

Comment: @JoeSaad what makes you think it's empty?

Comment: seeing it in the console in the <PostList /> component componentDidMount() method.. i'm doing console.log(this.props.list) is coming empty when passing this.props.post, but it is coming full when passing this.state.posts

Comment: Can you post a webpackbin showing the non-working code?

Comment: Can you add your entire Component? Your problem can be at React with props, can be at your Reducer that is not returning the data correctly, can be your combineReducers...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just attach to store in your child component? You can pass information where to attach if it's dynamic. Though passing store value by props sounds like a bad idea.

as for your example - `this.props.posts` props are intial values, re-render is not caused by props change inside your scope. Clearer explaination:
If parent changes props of child component - that cause re-rerender. 
If parent changes it's own props then no re-rerender triggered. (this.props shouldn't be mutated)

If you want to cause an action use state - pass props to state. Then any manipulation on state will cause re-render of child.

`<PostList list={ this.state.posts }></PostList>`

Attaching to redux-state is triggered after your props are created therefore it's empty when child is called and (as said above) it won't trigger re-render.

---

**edited**:

Well, my answer was a bit chaotic. Let me try again.

Solution:

attach to store or wherever you get your data and pass this data to 
`this.state.posts = data`. In constructor of your component set default state, like `this.state = { posts: [] }` (or whatever structure is required). In `render()` change your call for child into `<PostList list={ this.state.posts }></PostList>` and there you have it.

Notice:

Anyways since you're using redux I believe it would be better if you'd just attach to redux store inside your child component.